# Print to the console while user is typing

Tags: java

In Java, when you print to the console while a user is typing. It will destroy what is being typed. Let's say I have a server set up, and you can run commands from the server. Then this is what it might look like.

```
I'm trClient connected to server
ying to typMessage received from client
e a command
```

Is there a way to get around this? To have the text be printed on the line above the user is typing on. If you've ever ran a Minecraft server, you might know what I'm talking about. It would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b23UA.gif).

Since Minecraft is made using Java, I know that this is possible, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Thats nothing you could fix with Java. It's the terminal doing things wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it like this.
You have one `while loop` with a value of `true`.
Everything that the user enters is entered in the `ArrayList` and every time the user enters something that list is printed.
If you want it to print only the entered message, you can empty it each time you print the list.

There you could use `LinkedList` where when you drag all the variables from the list, it remains empty.

Comment: What would that look like? How would everything the user enters be store in an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library that gives terminal support, you can use `com.googlecode.lanterna` for your own terminal where you can set where you want to show the inputs given by the user. You can add the dependency to your program:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.lanterna/lanterna -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.lanterna</groupId>
    <artifactId>lanterna</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can use the `Terminal` of this library and do such manual positioning of input and printed test like the way you want the interface.

Have a our on [this page](http://mabe02.github.io/lanterna/apidocs/3.0/com/googlecode/lanterna/package-summary.html) and browse more to gather knowledge on `lanterna`.

I've added a very basic code for reading input and showing that on the gui:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int row = 5, col = 5;
        Terminal terminal = new DefaultTerminalFactory().createTerminal();
        Screen screen = new TerminalScreen(terminal);

        TextGraphics tg = screen.newTextGraphics();
        screen.startScreen();


        KeyStroke key;
        List<Character> string = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("reading input");
            key = terminal.readInput();

            if (key != null && key.getCharacter() != null) {
                System.out.println("Key not null: " + key.getCharacter());
                // you can add more keypress checks, they have a lot of enums for this
                if (key.getKeyType() == KeyType.Enter) {
                    String str = string.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
                    System.out.println(col + " " + row + " " + str);
                    tg.putString(col, row, str);
                    string.clear();
                } else if (key.getKeyType() == KeyType.Escape) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    string.add(key.getCharacter());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Null input");
                break;
            }
            screen.refresh();
        }

        screen.stopScreen();
        System.exit(0);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```